# Python code without using async-await

Tags: python, async-await, yield

For the below coroutine using `async` keyword,

```
async def greeting_1(name):
    return 'Hello' + name
```

To run this coroutine, invoke `run(greeting_1('John'))`

```
def run(coro):
    try:
        coro.send(None)
    except StopIteration as e:
        return e.value
```

---

What is the equivalent code of `greeting_1` using `yield` statement? without using `async` keyword

Comment: What do you mean by "equivalent"? Do you just want a regular function that returns `'Hello' + name`? That's pretty easy to write. Do you want to create an async coroutine without `async` or `yield`? That's going to be about as absurdly awkward and impractical as creating a function without `def` or `lambda`.

Comment: @user2357112 Can you delete first two lines in your comment?

Comment: @user2357112  I think they want to make an equivalent coroutine using generator function (yield statement)

Comment: @wim: Rereading it, it does say "using `yield`" where I thought it said "without using `yield`".

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent coroutine using generator function:

```
>>> def greeting_1(name):
...     if 0:
...         yield
...     return 'Hello' + name
... 
>>> run(greeting_1('John'))
'HelloJohn'
```

Comment: why `greeting_1('John')` still returns generator object? despite `yield` statement is unreachable in your code.

Comment: How will Python know whether the yield is reachable or not?  What if in place of the `if 0:` we put instead `if random.choice([0, 1]):`? It has to be determined at function definition time whether it's a generator or not.

Comment: If for every async definition, there is a `yield` version, then why do we use async version?

Comment: Syntactic sugar .. the newer `async`/`await` syntax is more expressive and easier to read than implementing the same thing with generators.

Comment: users struggle in understanding where to use and not to use await keyword